# MongoDB Mongoose: Passing array in find query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I do my first project using **MongoDB** and **Mongoose**.

I wonder if is possible to use array in find query to retrieve all objects corresponding to array elements.

Please see the dummy code bellow.

```js
let allCategory = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

static async getItemByCategory(allCategory ) {
     const item = Item.find({ allCategory });
     return item;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the $in operator

```
Item.find({ category : { $in : allCategory }, ...});
```

or $all depends on your need

```
Item.find({ category : { $all : allCategory }, ...});
```

Please checkout [Mongo query documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Juanes!